# Diagnostics, where to read the Trace.TraceInformation?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

```
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Try starting: {0}", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()));
Trace.Flush();
```

I have read: [How to Check the Application Event Log for Errors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx)

But I can not find any traces! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect tracing to end up in the event log? Did you configure it to write there? Start by reading [MSDN: Tracing and Instrumenting Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically the "Output from Tracing" section.

Comment: Sorry I long fixed this problem! I wish to remove this question. I copied code and configuration from another project and it is working now.

Comment: That's not how it works, especially not once answered. See also [How can I delete my post on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @CodeCaster : please flag this question for removal by admin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Trace can output to multiple listeners.

These can include debug (visual studio), file and even database listeners.

By default the Trace outputs to the Visual Studio [output window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx).

This article describes how to configure a file trace listener: [How to: Create and Initialize Trace Listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The System.Diagnostics.Debug and System.Diagnostics.Trace classes send messages to objects called listeners that receive and process these messages. One such listener, the System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener, is automatically created and initialized when tracing or debugging is enabled. If you want Trace or Debug output to be directed to any additional sources, you must create and initialize additional trace listeners.

Via the app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Or via code:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("TextWriterOutput.log", "myListener"));
```

If you want to log to the Event Log then you can use the [Event Log Trace Listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you andy, but I already knew how to write to file. I want to write to the application event log.

Comment: Oh, okay well you need to find a trace listener that will write to the application event log.

Comment: I've added a link to the Trace Listener I think you want.

Comment: I upvoted you. And even accepted your answer. I should not have asked this question, as I could have resolved it by opening another project I have in maintenance here.